# python pandas Access Excel MemoryError

Tags: python, excel, pandas, ms-access

All,

I've been trying to use pandas in python to load a table from access then write the data to an excel file see following code:

When running it the code (python 3.5.2) I receive the following output:

```
<!-- language: Python -->

import pandas as pd
import pypyodbc

conn = 'DSN=MyDSNTest'

cnxn = pypyodbc.connect(conn)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
qy = """select * from mytbl;"""
df = pd.read_sql(qy, cnxn)

cnxn.commit()
crsr.close()
cnxn.close()

print ("read into dataframe")
#writer = pd.ExcelWriter('c:/tmp/test.xlsx')
#df.to_excel(writer, 'Data')

df.to_excel('E:/Reports/AnalyticsInput/tblHistoryAC.xlsx', Data',index=False)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
#writer.save()
```

---

> read into dataframe   199966   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\jeff\test.py", line 23, in 
>       df.to_excel('c:/tmp/MyTest.xlsx', 'Data', index=False)     File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1466, in
>   to_excel
>       excel_writer.save()     File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 790, in
>   save
>       return self.book.save(self.path)     File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line
>   345, in save
>       save_workbook(self, filename)     File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 266,
>   in save_workbook
>       writer.save(filename)     File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 248,
>   in save
>       self.write_data()     File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 81,
>   in write_data
>       self._write_worksheets()     File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 197,
>   in _write_worksheets
>       xml = ws._write()     File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py",
>   line 870, in _write
>       return write_worksheet(self)     File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\worksheet.py", line
>   107, in write_worksheet
>       write_rows(xf, ws)   MemoryError

While the file is 200,000 rows I'd have to believe there is something else or another way to produce the xlsx file without getting a memory error.

Any ideas?  Thanks!
Jeff

Comment: Why not use Access functionality to export as an Excel file if this is your end-goal? If not, try writing to CSV and opening in Excel.

Comment: That is an avenue I've pursued but currently am running into problems between 32 and 64 bit drivers.  I haven't given up on that approach but so far it's been fraught with dead-ends and challenges as well.

Comment: Are you missing a quotation mark around Data?

Comment: The stacktrace mentions openpyxl, whose [documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) says that "There is support for the popular [lxml](http://lxml.de/) library which will be used if it is installed. This is particular useful when creating large files." You might try that.

Comment: To @xidgel:  I don't think so but will check... tried to change file for posting and may have messed that up... but I will check for that.  Thanks!

Comment: To @Gord Thompson...  thanks I will try openpyxl and see if it makes a difference... will respond when I know.  Thanks!